# reading Play application configuration file containing nested objects

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I want to get list of email IDs based on provided fileType and companyName

```
def getEmailAddresses(fileType: String, companyName: String): List[String] = {
  val xz = Play.application.configuration.getConfigList("email_list")
  println(xz)
}
```

my above function is giving me some complex List of Configuration which is not easily traversable.

I basically want `List[String]` which is nothing but list of email IDs.

For example, given arguments :

- fileType = test_2
- companyName = company2

I want to obtain String `"user1@gmail.com, user2@gmail.com"` 
that can be converted to `List[String]` by `.split(",").toList`

can this be simplified?

following is my application.conf file in scala play application

```
email_list = [
  {
    file0 : "user1@gmail.com,user2@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    file1 : [
      {"company1" : "user1@gmail.com"},
      {"company2" : "user1@gmail.com"},
      {"company3" : "user1@gmail.com"}
    ]
  },
  {
    top2 = [
      {"company1": "user1@gmail.com,user2@gmail.com"},
      {"company2": "user1@gmail.com,user2@gmail.com"},
      {"company3": "user1@gmail.com,user2@gmail.com"}
    ]
  },
  {
    test_2 = [
      {"company1": "user1@gmail.com,user2@gmail.com"},
      {"company2": "user1@gmail.com,user2@gmail.com"},
      {"company3": "user1@gmail.com,user2@gmail.com"}
    ]
  },
  {
    xyz_7 = [
      {"company1": "user1@gmail.com,user2@gmail.com"},
      {"company2": "user1@gmail.com,user2@gmail.com"},
      {"company3": "user1@gmail.com,user2@gmail.com"}
    ]
  },
  {
    abc_def = [
      {"company1": "user1@gmail.com,user2@gmail.com"},
      {"company2": "user1@gmail.com,user2@gmail.com"},
      {"company3": "user1@gmail.com,user2@gmail.com"}
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: If you are reading it from `application.conf`, why you don't structure it in a simpler way to be read/transversed??

Comment: @Salem for better readability i have modularized it based on file_types.

Answer (score 0):

I have done some trials on HOCON Syntax and found following code + config to be working

code

```
    def getEmailAddresses(fileType: String, companyName: String): List[String] = {
        // fileType = "file1"
        // companyName = "company1"

        val file0 = Play.application.configuration.getString("email_list.file0")
        println(file0)

        val file1_company1 = Play.application.configuration.getString(s"email_list.${fileType}.${companyName}")
        println(file1_company1)
    }
```

application conf

```
email_list {

    file0 = "user1@gmail.com,user2@gmail.com"

    file1 {
      company1 = "user1@gmail.com"
      company2 = "user1@gmail.com"
      company3 = "user1@gmail.com"
    }

    top2 {
      company1 = "user1@gmail.com,user2@gmail.com"
      company2 = "user1@gmail.com,user2@gmail.com"
      company3 = "user1@gmail.com,user2@gmail.com"
    }

    test_2 {
      company1 = "user1@gmail.com,user2@gmail.com"
      company2 = "user1@gmail.com,user2@gmail.com"
      company3 = "user1@gmail.com,user2@gmail.com"
    }

    xyz_7  {
      company1 = "user1@gmail.com,user2@gmail.com"
      company2 = "user1@gmail.com,user2@gmail.com"
      company3 = "user1@gmail.com,user2@gmail.com"
    }

    abc_def  {
      company1 = "user1@gmail.com,user2@gmail.com"
      company2 = "user1@gmail.com,user2@gmail.com"
      company3 = "user1@gmail.com,user2@gmail.com"
    }
}
```